# What if Modern Furniture was Brought to the Renaissance?

Tags: time-travel, trade, renaissance

A protagonist equipped with unstable time traveling powers is shopping at their local furniture store when they realize their powers will knock them back to the Renaissance period.

They only have a set amount of time to grab whatever is near them before they’re transported. Anything within a two meter square radius around them will be transported, without worrying about truncation.

The protagonist decides to grab enough goods so that they can use them for trade to gain a foothold when they arrive in the past. Assuming the security guards don’t take down the protagonist before they’ve amassed this pile of goods, what *category of items*, should they focus on grabbing from the store?

Most importantly, would this type of goods being transported back in time be enough to allow the protagonist to gain enough of an economic foothold to change history itself?

---

I am also interested in whether any category of mass-manufactured goods of today, now considered low-end, would be worth significantly more in the past. For example, we take for granted the extremely fine-tuned manufacturing techniques of today, but no technologies existed back then that could easily mimic the precision of factory-manufactured goods. This could include finely-made glassware, precisely assembled furniture, smoothed and rust-proof utensils, etc. There are also certain materials like aluminum, plastic, and some textiles that also wouldn’t have existed back then. What categories of modern, mass-manufactured furniture and furnishings from the store would be worth the most in that period?

To constrain the question somewhat:

- The powers cannot transport any other living beings
- Anything electronic transferred will self-destruct in transition
- The protagonist can only grab items from the furniture store
- The furniture store comes stocked with the following categories of items: furniture( tables, chairs, desks, wardrobes), utensils, table decorations, glassware, rugs, printed paintings, curtains/drapes/bedcovers and any other categories of furniture that may belong.

Comment: Are you sure this is about building a world and not about a plot element?

Comment: @L.Dutch-ReinstateMonica Thanks for the feedback, I restructured my question to he more specific about the furniture rather than the plot, hopefully it is not in a better state.

Comment: Easy. Glassware, glassware and more glassware. Modern glass would appear as almost magically perfect to Renaissance buyers. By contrast, modern so-called furniture would appear as extremely poorly made and of substandard materials. (It appears poorly made and of substandard materials to anybody old enough to have experienced real furniture made of real wood.) Also, rugs (if the shop is more upmarket and sells real rugs made of real wool) *may* have some value. By the way, **the** thing to bring would be buttons. Two cubic meters of various sorts of buttons would set the hero up for life.

Comment: @AlexP great point, why not add this as an answer to be considered?

Comment: I am of the same opinion as @L.Dutch-ReinstateMonica.

Comment: Being in a fabric store would be much better. A few bolts of brightly colored permanently died polyester, nice and shiny and as evenly woven as the finest silk, should keep the traveler in luxury for a long time.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan you’re right, but curtains, blankets and the like could also be repurposed for this too, and they would also be compressible. I think this is valid as an answer as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Knives.**

[image: knife]

1. Compact, so you can bring all that the store has.
2. Compact, so you can hide them on your person and move freely.  You can cache some for later retrieval in case you are robbed.
3. Useful.  The utility of a knife like this is immediately evident to anyone, regardless of station in life, and even if they cannot read that it is a utility knife.  On arrival, you can sell a knife or trade it for food with the people you first meet.
4. The unusual appearance, high quality, and rustproof nature of these knives will make them intriguing and valuable to people who have money.

Comment: Great points, thanks for the thoughtful answer. Would it be useful to include some knife grinders as well?

Comment: @Enthus3d In what ways would modern knife grinders be better than whetstones etc.? Poor quality metal meant a lot of knife, scythe, axe etc. sharpening. How long they hold an edge would be one of the selling points of the time traveler's knives.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan I was thinking along the lines of modern knife grinders that make it easy for the common people to sharpen their knives, like the one [here](https://m.thebay.com/zwilling-international-k-elements-sharpener/product/0600090048526?&site_refer=CSE_GGLPLA:GSE+-+Shopping+-+Showcase:GSE+-+Shopping+-+Showcase+-+Home&gclid=CjwKCAiA5JnuBRA-EiwA-0ggPV68oHDQuGN7qSkOczbC3BeOdG4RgZWsJl25co1SpWZHPmr2Am8zxxoC-rQQAvD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds). Both products together and their special materials would make it seem especially magical

Comment: Near the knives, there may be a display of spice racks. If any contain filled jars of spices, you have hit the jackpot.